# Implement file manager in my android Manager

Tags: android, file-manager

I've tried to make a FileManager for my android phone, I'm very newbie in Java... I found this source I want to implement it in my source code, and I want control everything when pressing menu button in app.

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileUtils {

  public static boolean delete(String path) {
    final File deleteTarget = new File(path);
    return delete(deleteTarget);
  }

  public static boolean delete(File targetFile) {
    boolean deleted = true;
    try {
      deleted = targetFile.delete();
      if(!deleted && ! targetFile.isFile()) {
        throw new Exception(String.format("File could not be deleted. Path: %s", targetFile.getAbsolutePath()));
      }
      deleted = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      deleted = false;
    }

    return deleted;
  }

  public static boolean createDirectory(File directory) {
    boolean created = true;
    try {
      created = directory.mkdirs();
      if(!created && ! directory.isDirectory()) {
        throw new Exception(String.format("Directory could not be created. Path: %s", directory.getAbsolutePath()));
      }
      created = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      created = false;
    }

    return created;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain  - "i want control everything"

Comment: Simon sorry for my bad lang, i'm from Romania. Wen i press menu button   and chose Delete to appear box to select file who want deleted.

Comment: A much better (and easier to code) way is to present the files in a ListView.  Then show the menu when the user presses the Menu button or, when the touch and hold a file.  This is the "Android" way.

Comment: Yes this is the anwser but how i do it ?

Comment: @Simon How implement delete in void function ?